# Difference between build.gradle api project(path: ':libName') vs api project(':libName') (PATH: keyword)

Tags: android, build.gradle

What is the meaning of the "path:" keyword in this statement and what is he difference between specifying it and leaving it out.

```
build.gradle 

dependencies {
     api project(path: ':someName') 
     ...
vs 
dependencies {
     api project(':someName') 
     ...
```

Does leaving it out simply default to 'path:'?
Does path refer to the project root?
Is there syntax to specify a path to a dependency at a specific location?
Are there other keywords to use at this location inside project()?